# Is there a general term for greater/less than operators in Python?

Tags: python, math, syntax, terminology

I've been working on a Python package which includes functionality for creating queries, which is implemented by overloading the Python operators `==`, `!=`, `>=`, `<=`, `>`, `<` on certain classes in the package (the syntax of it all is very similar to filtering/indexing on a Pandas DataFrame).

In the process of writing the documentation I found myself looking for a general term for the Python `<=` and `>=` operators - here's a snippet from the sentence:

> ... using the Python inequality operators `<=` and `>=`...

I later used the term *'**strict**  inequality operators'* to refer to `>` and `<`.

I realised my mathematics background was showing, as these are the terms that would be used there (specifically to contrast with the mathematical `=` for the world of equations), but I don't that necessarily carries into the Python world. Particularly since *inequality operator* be confused with `!=`.

All six come under the term *comparison operators* (e.g. [the official language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) and [this Real Python tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-operators-expressions/#comparison-operators)), but my question is:
**Is there a term that covers the four operators `<=` `>=` `<` `>`?** (and specifically *not* `==` `!=`)

---

I realise I can solve my documentation problem by using the term *comparison operators* and making it clear which ones I'm referring to within that category by listing them. But I'm still curious about this question.

Comment: Even when referring to specifically those 4, I'd still use the term "comparison operators" (and use [in]equality operators to refer to the other 2). But whose benefit is this for? The point of common nomenclature is to eliminate ambiguity when discussing these things with other people. If what you define as "comparison operators" is different than what someone else might use that term for, that's going to be a source of miscommunication and confusion.

Comment: Inequality operators?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly why I'm asking the question @Abion47 - I realised the term I'd naturally reached for might not be universally understood in the same way.

Comment: https://data-flair.training/blogs/python-comparison-operators/

Comment: So, when you put something like `what are less than and greater than operators called` into a search engine and [got results](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=what+are+less+than+and+greater+than+operators+called) such as [this](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/operators-greater-less-used-compare-data-conditions-called-operators--smooth-b-arithmetic--q63451240) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_operator), and [this](https://eecs.oregonstate.edu/ecampus-video/CS161/template/chapter_4/relational.html), how exactly did they fail to answer the question for you?

Comment: Thanks @KarlKnechtel - couple of issues: 1) I was searching for terms used in the Python world, so that wasn't the exact search I entered and 2) the sources you link to use the term *relational operator* for all six operators; if you read the question properly (the bit I helpfully emphasised in bold at the end) you would have seen I was after a term that _doesn't_ include `==` and `!=` 

Comment: I don't understand why you think `==` and `!=` should be considered a different kind of operator from the others.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel because in the part of the documentation I'm working on, I'm referring to those four and not the other two. It's not that I have a fundamental disagreement with the Python language syntax  just that I want to refer to only those four at this point.

Comment: "Relational operator" could cover far more operators than just these 6 (and can certainly be used to describe `is`, `is not`, `in`, and `not in` as well). It's not well known, but *ordering operator* would certainly be more descriptive of the four in question without implying `==` or `!=`.

Comment: @Levi I do appreciate your willingness to help, but it is slightly comical when the suggestion you make was the *exact* term that I consider in my question and then dismiss for reasons I carefully explain. Of course, if you think I was wrong to dismiss it that's fine, but in that case it would help if you'd offer a little explanation. As it is, it kind of looks like you didn't read the question... 

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: They're semantically quite different. Having a natural ordering is a much stronger requirement than having a natural equality relation, and far fewer types support order comparison than equality comparison.

Comment: @PM77-1 I don't want to appear rude or ungrateful, but your link was actually one I'd come across in my research but dismissed because it's using the term _comparison operator_ and uses it to refer to all 6 operators. I'm wanting a term to cover just 4 of them. I did explain all this in the text of the question...

Comment: @Tim oups, I didn't read your question carefully. You're right, also inequality does not fit `>=` since it will be true for equal terms as well. The word "comparison" would be then closest to the truth IMO. Or perhaps don't give them a common name at all, just enumerate them in the docs.

Comment: Yeah @Levi I think that's what I'll do, though perhaps still use the term 'comparison operator' to narrow it down and then list the ones within that I'm referring to at the time 

Comment: In Python, the comparison operators are an even bigger superset of `>=`, `<=`, `<`, and `>` than the one that also contains `==` and `!=`.

Comment: Interesting, @chepner! Are you saying that there are other operators that fit the term, apart from those six?

Comment: Yes, I mentioned them above: Python considers `is`, `is not`, `in`, and `not in` to be comparison operators, as least as far as comparison chaining is concerned. `a == b in c` is the same as `a == b and b in c`, just as `a == b == c` is `a == b and b == c`.

Comment: The chaining is strictly syntactic; `0 in [1,2,3] < 5` is legal and evaluates to `False`, even if `[1,2,3] < 5` isn't defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Order comparison" is what the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) use. It emphasizes the importance of an order relation rather than mere equality and inequality, and it clearly excludes `!=`.

Comment: FWIW, I think I'm going to stick with _comparison operator_ and then specify the ones I mean within that, because the context isn't really about ordering but rather me hijacking the syntax to create data queries matching those conditions. I think throwing the term 'order' brings up the wrong kind of idea and I don't think it's as well-known as a term. BUT I do really appreciate finding the right term for `<=` `>=` `<` `>` which was the question I asked. 